ETC update query does not return modified object spring data jpa
I have a spring data jpa method that update a table based on a condition and return an object in case the update is happened or empty if the update is not happening. The database is postgres
the method is
@Transactional
@Query(value = "WITH existing_batch AS (" +
        "    SELECT j.config_key, bt.job_tracker_id, bt.batch_number " +
        "    FROM hibernate.batch_tracker bt " +
        "    JOIN hibernate.job_tracker jt ON bt.job_tracker_id = jt.id " +
        "    JOIN hibernate.job j ON j.id = jt.job_id " +
        "    WHERE bt.id = :batchId" +
        "), " +
        "update_batch AS (" +
        "    UPDATE hibernate.batch_tracker " +
        "    SET batch_location = CONCAT(:s3RootLocation, '/', " +
        "                                (SELECT config_key FROM existing_batch), " +
        "                                '/job_tracker_', (SELECT job_tracker_id FROM existing_batch), " +
        "                                '/batch_', (SELECT batch_number FROM existing_batch), '___', :batchId), " +
        "        status = :status " +
        "    WHERE id = :batchId " +
        "      AND NOT EXISTS ( " +
        "          SELECT 1 " +
        "          FROM hibernate.batch_tracker b " +
        "          WHERE b.job_tracker_id = (SELECT job_tracker_id FROM existing_batch) " +
        "              AND b.batch_number = (SELECT batch_number FROM existing_batch) " +
        "              AND b.id <> :batchId) " +
        "    RETURNING * " +
        ") " +
        "SELECT * FROM update_batch", 
        nativeQuery = true)
Optional<BatchTracker> updateBatchIfNoDuplicates(Long batchId, String s3RootLocation, String status);

The integration test is
public class BatchTrackerRepositoryIntegrationTest extends BaseRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private BatchTrackerRepository batchTrackerRepository;

@Autowired
private JobTrackerRepository jobTrackerRepository;

@Autowired
private JobRepository jobRepository;

private Job job;
private JobTracker jobTracker;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    job = jobRepository.save(new Job("fakeConfig", "fakeAPICriteria", "fakeName", "fakeSponsorCode", 1L, "fakeSpecCode"));
    jobTracker = jobTrackerRepository.save(new JobTracker(job));
}

@Test
public void testUpdateBatchIfNoDuplicates() {
    BatchTracker tracker = new BatchTracker(jobTracker);
    tracker.setBatchNumber(22L);
    tracker.setPreviousPagePersonId(13000L);
    tracker = batchTrackerRepository.saveAndFlush(tracker);

    Optional<BatchTracker> result = batchTrackerRepository.updateBatchIfNoDuplicates(tracker.getId(), "location", "COMPLETED");
    assertTrue("the batch should be updated with the location and status", result.isPresent());
    BatchTracker bt = result.get();
    assertTrue(bt.getId() > 0);
    assertEquals(tracker.getBatchNumber(), bt.getBatchNumber());
    assertEquals(tracker.getPreviousPagePersonId(), bt.getPreviousPagePersonId());
    assertEquals(tracker.getJobTracker().getId(), bt.getJobTracker().getId());
    assertEquals("COMPLETED", bt.getStatus());
    assertEquals("location", bt.getBatchLocation());
    batchTrackerRepository.deleteAll();
}

assertEquals("COMPLETED", bt.getStatus());
assertEquals("location", bt.getBatchLocation()); both failed because the updateBatchIfNoDuplicates returns the pre update object; however if I run the query in the database directly it return the update object.
the batch tracker class I am going to update is
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "batch_tracker")
public class BatchTracker extends BaseEntity {

    public BatchTracker() {
    }

    public BatchTracker(JobTracker jobTracker) {
        this.jobTracker = jobTracker;
        this.status = BatchStatus.STARTED;
    }

    public enum BatchStatus {
        STARTED, COMPLETED
    }

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_tracker_id", nullable = false)
    private JobTracker jobTracker;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private BatchStatus status;

    @Column(name = "previous_page_person_id", nullable = false)
    private Long previousPagePersonId;

    @Column(name = "batch_location", nullable = false)
    private String batchLocation;

    @Column(name = "batch_number")
    private Long batchNumber;

    public void populateBatchLocation(String rootLocation) {
        // using a root location, builds and sets a proper hierarchical s3 location
        String location = String.format("%s/%s/job_tracker_%d/batch_%d___%d", rootLocation, jobTracker.getJob().getConfigKey(),
                jobTracker.getId(), getBatchNumber(), getId());
        // the result will look similar to:
        // s3://intersystems-dev/ebay_lyra/job_tracker_1003/batch_1___1010
        setBatchLocation(location);
    }
}


any help how can I get the modified object?
